# Calling an external API with keys and certificate from cloudpage

Tags: api, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

We are trying to call an external API (Post request) with certificates and keys from SF cloud web page.
When we are calling the API from a linux machine (using CURL) it is working fine as we are able to provode the path for the certificate and key like in below syntax -

```
curl --key <key file path> --cert <cert file path> -X POST <api endpoint> -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'client_id:<client id>' -H 'client_secret: <secret key>' -H 'Authorization: Basic <auth token>' -d '{  "FIRST_NAME": "Ashley"}'
Response: OK
```

Does any one have an idea, how to configure the same post request in SF cloud page? (We have tried running AMP Script but we are not able to find a way to pass these certificates and keys).

Comment: [salesforce.se] SE has answers to this question

Comment: can you please point a link for the answer?